mysql command isnot working in xampp
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 170
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 211212 23:11:59
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-12-12 23:11:59 0 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.4.22-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300306
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 300315; transaction id 170
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-12-12 23:13:31 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.


The first place to look in this case is the Windows event log, specifically the Application events, see if the reason for the server crashing is logged there.
